# Verify group of process was set correctly when launched

Tags: linux, permissions, group

I am setting the group of a process when I launch it by doing the following:

```
sudo -g offline "/home/natral/apps/some-app/bin/app.sh" %f
```

after the process is running how can I verify the name of the user and group it is running as? I checked `ps aux` and this would tell me the user but not the group. Then I tried `ps -eo uid,gid,args` and managed to find the GID but how can I verify that the GID is indeed the group "offline"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `user` and `group` in place of `uid` and `gid` to have `ps` show you the group and user names instead of the numbers. And of course, if you have the process id, you don't need to browse the whole list `ps -e` gives you, but could just use something like this

```
$ ps -o pid,user,group,args -p "$pid"
```

or if you don't have the PID, `pgrep` could find it for you:

```
$ ps -o pid,user,group,args -p $(pgrep -f app.sh)
```

But I do suspect `sudo` would give an error if it couldn't set the group id to the one you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the GID value, `getent group $GID` will give you back all details regarding group whose id is `$ID` including its name.

Alternatively you can also do `getent group offline` and see if the number you get back is the one you see in `ps` output.

Comment: I get a result saying offline:x:1003: what does the x mean here?

Comment: It is a placeholder (for the group password, like user have passwords, groups can have too, but AFAIK this feature is nowhere used nowadays), so as long as you get a reply you are fine.